# Problem in snap7 library and modules calling

Tags: python, dll, operating-system, spyder, plc

```
import snap7 
from snap7 import client
client = snap7.client.Client
```

My above code is running while the followig code schould run on spyder:

```
import snap7 
from snap7 import client
client = snap7.client.Client()
```

''()'' using small parenthesis changes the story I don't know why its happening?
Do anybody know this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. this code is running on Python shell. I can connect my plc and can access data blocks and internal memories.
The code is also running on spyder IDE just copy paste snap7.dll to the script folder of Anaconda (Since I have installed spyder through anaconda).
Anways I can run my code on Spyder and Python shell both.